# error: undefined reference to 'ConvertUtf8ToKString(char const*)'

Tags: c++, android-studio, c++11, android-ndk, clang++

I try. to compile a lib with Android Studio. If I compile the lib with CMAKE on Linux everything went fine. With Android Studio I always get the error:

```
error: undefined reference to 'ConvertUtf8ToKString(char const*)'
```

This confuse me. The function is definitely found in the referenced CPP file.

The complete function is:

```
bool BsdSockServer::ReceiveAnswer(KString &refStrAnswer)
{

    static const int utf8BuffSize = UTF8_BUFF_SIZE;
    static char utf8Buff[UTF8_BUFF_SIZE];
    int res = recv(m_socket, utf8Buff, utf8BuffSize, 0);
    if(res == -1)
    {
        throw FDBException(FDB_EXC_CONNECTION_ERROR);
    }
    if(res == 0)
    {
        throw FDBException(FDB_EXC_CONNECTION_CLOSED);
    }

    if(res >= utf8BuffSize)
    {
        throw FDBException(FDB_EXC_TOO_BIG_ANSWER);
    }

    utf8Buff[res] = char(0);

    refStrAnswer = ConvertUtf8ToKString(utf8Buff); //<----- LINE

    return true;
}
```

The function in the KString class is:

```
KString ConvertUtf8ToKString(const char* szString)
{
    size_t nSrcLength = strlen(szString);
    wchar_t* wszBuffer = new wchar_t[nSrcLength + 1];

    utf2wcs(wszBuffer, szString, int(nSrcLength + 1));

    KString result(wszBuffer);
    delete[] wszBuffer;
    return result;
}
```

In my eyes there is everything ok. Why the NDK compile nag around?
I also checked the compiler and CMAKE flags and there is nothing different. 
Compiler is always clang with c+11.

The important Gradle lines are:

```
        ndk { // these platforms cover 99% percent of all Android devices
            //abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            abiFilters 'x86_64'
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-29', '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE', '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
                cFlags '-O3', '-fsigned-char' // full optimization, char data type is signed
                cppFlags '-std=c++11', '-fsigned-char', '-fPIC'
            }
        }
```

Inside the CMakeList.txt I defined the include directories:

```
include_directories(${SDK_SOURCE_DIR}/Development/SDK)
include_directories(${SDK_SOURCE_DIR}/Development/SDK/FrameWork)
```

I think that the Gradle native build cannot recognize the include directories inside he CMakeList.txt. I thought this is a global parameter.

Anybody can give me a tip why this compile error happen?

As requested, the KString header:

```
#ifndef __KSTRING_H__
#define __KSTRING_H__

#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <clocale>

class LocaleSetter
{
public:
    LocaleSetter()
    {
#ifdef WIN32
        setlocale(LC_ALL, ".ACP");      
#else
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
#endif
    }
};

/// Helper class intended to convert strings to upper and lower case (???? make a correct description)
class KString: private LocaleSetter
{
public: 
    typedef int index_t;

    /// Construct empty string
    KString();
    /// Copy from another string
    KString(const KString &String);
    /// Copy from multibyte string
    KString(const char *szString);
    /// Copy from Unicode string
    KString(const wchar_t *wszString);
    /// Construct single-symbol string
    explicit KString(char Char);
    /// Construct single-symbol string from Unicode symbol
    explicit KString(wchar_t wChar);
    /// Construct string of length 'nLength' filled with 'wChar'
    KString(size_t nLength, wchar_t wChar);
    /// Construct string of length 'nLenght' using non-zero-terminated multibyte string 'pChar'
    KString(const char* pChar, size_t nLength);

    /// UTF8 representation
    const char* GetAsUtf8() const;
#ifdef WIN32
    const char* GetAsUtf8Old() const;
#endif

    ~KString();

    /// Clear string
    void Empty();

    //Operators
    const KString &operator =(const KString &String);
    const KString &operator =(const char *szString);
    const KString &operator =(const wchar_t *wszString);
    const KString &operator =(char Char);
    const KString &operator =(wchar_t wChar);

    const KString &operator +=(const KString &String);
    const KString &operator +=(const char *szString);
    const KString &operator +=(const wchar_t *wszString);
    const KString &operator +=(const char Char);
    const KString &operator +=(const wchar_t wChar);

    bool operator <(const KString &String) const;
    bool operator <(const char *szString) const;
    bool operator <(const wchar_t *wszString) const;
    bool operator >(const KString &String) const;
    bool operator >(const char *szString) const;
    bool operator >(const wchar_t *wszString) const;

    bool operator ==(const KString &String) const;
    bool operator ==(const char *szString) const;
    bool operator ==(const wchar_t *wszString) const;
    bool operator ==(char Char) const;
    bool operator ==(wchar_t wChar) const;

    bool operator !=(const KString &String) const;
    bool operator !=(const char *szString) const;
    bool operator !=(const wchar_t *wszString) const;
    bool operator !=(char Char) const;
    bool operator !=(wchar_t wChar) const;

    friend KString operator+( const KString& str1, const KString& str2 );
    friend KString operator+( const KString& str1, wchar_t *psz2 );
    friend KString operator+( wchar_t *psz1, const KString& str2 );
    friend KString operator+( const KString& str1, wchar_t ch2 );
    friend KString operator+( const KString& str1, char ch2 );
    friend KString operator+( wchar_t ch1, const KString& str2 );
    friend KString operator+( char ch1, const KString& str2 );

    operator const char*() const;
    operator const wchar_t*() const;

    TCHAR operator [](index_t nIndex) const;

    ///////////////////////

    /// Returns amount of characters in the string
    size_t GetLength() const;           

    /// Sets new string length. Can only truncate string.
    void SetLength( size_t nLength );

    /// Returns pointer to modificable buffer at least nMinBufferLength
    TCHAR *GetBuffer( size_t nMinBufferLength );
    void ReleaseBuffer();

    /// Returns 'true' if string's length is 0
    bool IsEmpty() const throw();

    /// Truncate string to the given length. Equal to SetLength.
    void Truncate( size_t nNewLength );
    /// Deletes 'nCount' characters from position 'iIndex'
    size_t Delete( index_t iIndex, size_t nCount = 1 );

    /// Returns character from given position
    TCHAR GetAt( index_t iChar ) const;

    /// Returns character from giver position reverse
    TCHAR GetAtReverse(index_t iChar) const;

    /// Sets symbol at position 'iChar'
    void SetAt( index_t iChar, TCHAR tSym );

    /// Returns 'nAmount' of symbols from the beginning
    KString Left(size_t nAmount) const;
    /// Returns 'nAmount' of symbols from the end of a string
    KString Right(size_t nAmount) const;
    /// Return the substring starting at index 'iFirst'

    /// Cuts all symbols beginning from the nAmount - 1
    void KeepLeft(int nAmount);     
    /// Cuts all symbols except nAmount rightmost symbols (NULL - terminated character is not included)
    void KeepRight(int nAmount);    

    KString Mid( index_t iFirst ) const;
    /// Return the substring starting at index 'iFirst', with length 'nCount'
    KString Mid( index_t iFirst, size_t nCount ) const; 

    /// Remove all trailing whitespace
    KString& TrimRight();
    /// Remove all leading whitespace
    KString& TrimLeft();
    /// Remove all leading and trailing whitespace
    KString& Trim();
    /// Remove all leading and trailing occurrences of character 'chTarget'
    KString& Trim( wchar_t chTarget );
    // Remove all leading and trailing occurrences of any of the characters in the string 'pszTargets'
    //KString& Trim( wchar_t *pszTargets );
    // Remove all trailing occurrences of character 'chTarget'
    KString& TrimRight( wchar_t chTarget );
    // Remove all trailing occurrences of any of the characters in string 'pszTargets'
    KString& TrimRight( wchar_t *pszTargets );
    // Remove all leading occurrences of character 'chTarget'
    KString& TrimLeft( wchar_t chTarget );
    // Remove all leading occurrences of any of the characters in string 'pszTargets'
    KString& TrimLeft( wchar_t *pszTargets );

    KString& MakeUpper();   
    KString& MakeLower();
    KString  MakeUpperCopy() const;

    //return
    //\arg -1   If the current string is less than the passed one
    //\arg  0   If the current string is equal to the passed one
    //\arg  1   If the current string iw bigger than the passed one
    int CompareNoCase(const KString &String) const;
    int CompareNoCase(const char *szString) const;
    int CompareNoCase(const wchar_t *wszString) const;


    /* \brief Find
    *
    *   \return 
    *   \arg The zero-based index of the first character in this
    *   KString object that matches the requested substring or characters;
    *   \arg -1 if the substring or character is not found
    */
    index_t Find( const char *szSub ) const;
    index_t Find( const wchar_t *wszSub ) const;
    index_t Find( char ch, index_t nStart = 0 ) const;
    index_t Find( wchar_t wch, index_t nStart = 0 ) const;
    index_t Find( const char *szSub, index_t nStart ) const;
    index_t Find( const wchar_t *wszSub, index_t nStart ) const;

    index_t ReverseFind( char ch ) const;
    index_t ReverseFind( wchar_t wch ) const;

    // Format data using format string
    KString& Format( KString strFormat, ... );
    KString& Format( const wchar_t *pszFormat, ... );
    KString& Format( const char *pszFormat, ... );

    KString& FormatV( const wchar_t* pwszFormat, va_list args);
    KString& FormatV( const char* pszFormat, va_list args);

protected:
    void set(const KString &String);
    void set(const char *szString);
    void set(const wchar_t *wszString);
    void set(char Char);
    void set(wchar_t wChar);

private:
    wchar_t         *m_wszString;
    mutable char    *m_szTempString;
    size_t          m_dwLen;
};

// a-la printf formatting functions
KString KStringFormat(KString strFormat, ... );
KString KStringFormat(const wchar_t* pwszFormat, ... );
KString KStringFormat(const char* pszFormat, ... );

KString ConvertUtf8ToKString(const char* szString);
KString test();

bool operator ==(const char *szString, const KString &String);
bool operator ==(const wchar_t *wszString, const KString &String);
bool operator !=(const char *szString, const KString &String);
bool operator !=(const wchar_t *wszString, const KString &String);


#endif  //__KSTRING_H__
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I do not think that any reproducible example is needed. This will explode the scope completely because it will need a couple of days to do this. All the information are inside the question. All necessary files and code. I think it is a problem with the include paths in CMakeList.txt and gradle.

Comment: The function _inside_ the KString class? because in your example you dont call the method within the KString namespace you call a function with name `ConvertUtf8ToKString` within the _global_ namespace. You code shows it as just a global function though so a typo?

Comment: No, this is the right way, it is outside the KString Namespace. I will add this to the question.